# ActionMailer::Base render text view Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am trying to render only the text view, as a string, which I then need to send to a 3rd party via an API request.

My current plan is to render it just before the `mail` call in the class that inherits from ActionMailer::Base, but I'm open to different approaches.

I have both an html and text template available, but thus far I've been able to get the html version rendered, but even if I pass a format it still only gives me the html version.

My code to render is:

```
render {|format| format.text}
```

templates are named like this:

```
my_mailer/mailer_method.html.erb
my_mailer/mailer_method.text.erb
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the text version with a slight modification of the `render` line:

```
render formats: :text
```